# Creating new initrd without installing kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, compiling, initrd

How can i create initrd image for a new(experimental) kernel without actually installing it. 
(Existing tools to create initrd based on config and details from installed kernel.)

Say i compile a new kernel with experimental features turned on, i have this in another separate partition. I would like to boot into this kernel, for that will old initrd work ?
if i want to create a new initrd.img for new kernel without actually installing kernel, how can i do it ?

BTW, can someone clarify about initramfs ? will it be useful for my scenario ?

Comment: How did you create your current initrd?

Comment: If you compile a kernel with a given version, and the modules in the initrd are an older version, the kernel won't load them.

Comment: @phunehehe currently i build kernel from /usr/linux where kernel source is copied. which then installs related file directly to /boot. But i want to compile kernel in some sandbox directory and just use the kernel-image and initrd alone instead of updating other system files.

Comment: I don't really get it. What is preventing you from building the initrd without messing touching the kernel?

Comment: @phunehehe currently i am trying build via "mkinitramfs -o initrd.img 2.6.37" but my current running kernel is not 2.6.37. I get error cannot find "/lib/modules/2.6.37" i have compiled 2.6.37 but have not installed it (omitted steps "make install" and "make modules_install"). is it not possible to boot with just vmlinuz and initrd ? should i do make install too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating an initrd doesn't have anything to do with installing a kernel. All you do is to create a file structure for the initrd, copy the required files, write the init script and package all of that into a cpio archive. I used the [instructions in the Gentoo Wiki](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Initramfs) to make my initrd. Some distributions make tools to generate initrds, and for that you will have to name your distro. For example, Arch has [mkinitcpio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Configuring_mkinitcpio).

initramfs is just another (newer) [implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs#Implementation) of the initial ramdisk. I don't know for sure, but I think modern distributions all use initramfs. When you see "initrd", it may be a shorthand for "initial ramdisk", and thus it covers both initrd and initramfs.